# JPA Entities state in a stateless REST application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

we developed a spring boot application with spring data JPA and hibernate envers for revisions. I ask myself in generell in what  state we should write our entities.

Our responses deliver the resources which can be new (without id) or already persisted resources. We map the properties of the DTOs with the mapstruct framework.

Is it a common pattern to...

a) load an existing entity and then copy the state from our DTOs to the loaded entity? (if id is not set, we would have to create a new Entity) All properties on the entity would be replaced by the values of the DTO. This would happen in a transactional service method, which triggers the flush operation by its end. (Due to Spring Data JPA we work with repositories to execute the crud operations - in this case we call save() on our entities so that they get attached to the entitymanager).

b) Another pattern would be to ALWAYS create a new instance of the entity and copy the state from the DTOs to that new entity. The difference is that we don't load the entity (if already persisted) and the entitymanager would not contain the entity until we call the save method in our service method.

The two approaches lead to different behaviour of the entitymanager especially when it comes to optimistic locking. So what's your approach?

Comment: So what is your question actually ? The two approaches that you mentioned are two different use-cases . The 1st is the update case while the 2nd is the create case.  They are apple and orange , so what thing you want to compare between them ? I would says the steps that you describe in both cases are very common.

Comment: I missed one thing in my description: we use hibernate envers to save revisions of the entities. So the two approached differ not that much. The main thing i wanted to point out is that on the one hand the entity is immediately attached to the hibernate session aka. entitymanager. On the other hand i am working with a completely new entity until the transaction flushes.